# Unable to restart apache2 after installing SSL certificate

Tags: apache2, ssl

I installed an SSL certificate from Comodo. After I edited my default-ssl.conf, I encountered an error whilst trying to restart the apache2 service. 
PASTEBIN OF THE ERROR: http://pastebin.com/wyAvMNM0

Comment: Paste your /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf . It seems that there is an error there. Maybe you didn't add the path and filename of ssl certificate and key? Edit your question with the default-ssl.conf please.

Comment: The apache2 restarting error is fixed now, but the SSL doesn't work. http://pastebin.com/5gUKU9HH

Comment: What about to comment : `SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem` and 
        `SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key`  then restart the apache ? I think those are duplicate.

Comment: Do you mean I should delete them? @NikolayNikolov

Comment: Mm... i think this is cloudflare issue.  Go to your cloudflare and disable `Always use https`

If you run from your terminal : `curl -I swayforums.com -L` you will see the redirect loop.

Comment: Put # in front of them or Delete - same sh*t :)

Comment: @NikolayNikolov Done that, when I went to https:// it redirected me to the http:// version = no SSL

Comment: Yes, it seems now it's forums issue :) Go to your forums settings and change the url to https:// 

I can see with curl that your SSL works fine :
`mac-mini:~ nikolay$ curl -I https://swayforums.com -L
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: cloudflare-nginx
Date: Mon, 04 Jan 2016 14:08:40 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d25ad134d0aff3fa3e024f6d75d883fc41451916520; expires=Tue, 03-Jan-17 14:08:40 GMT; path=/; domain=.swayforums.com; HttpOnly
Location: http://swayforums.com/
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
CF-RAY: 25f7844e6f22235a-FRA
`

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 problems :

1. There are duplicate files about `SSLCertificateFile` and `SSLCertificateKeyFile` which should be removed.
2. There is and cloudflare setting that should be disabled - `Always use https`
3. From the forums settings, the URL should be changed to https:// and the 301 redirect will be fine.

I hope this can help you @whitz

Comment: 1) I added an # to the beginning of the files like you said, attempted to restart apache2. An error occured. http://pastebin.com/WCbTPH7x2 2) Disabled that. 3) Did that, didn't work.

Comment: Ok, put them back like were before.

Comment: OK, I removed everything from the default-ssl and added: <VirtualHost swayforums.com:443>

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/swayforums.com.key
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/swayforums_com.crt
</virtualHost> restarted apache2 seems fine.. but https:// doesn't work.

Comment: It is still cloudflare issue. Try disabling SSL from Crypto tab. Other ways, from cloudflare you can use their free valid ssl, so there are no needs to set SSL virtual host. Why you don't do it like that way?

Comment: That's disabled, enable HSTS is also disabled and I don't know.. I paid for my SSL so I want to make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite clear:

```
Jan 04 14:41:21 vps231844.ovh.net apache2[1622]: SSLCertificateChainFile takes one argument, SSL Server CA Certificate Chain file ('/path/to/file' - PEM encoded)
```

What you should do is to remove the whole line `SSLCertificateChainFile` which is an optional directive.

Comment: Thanks.. I guess apache2 restarts now. But unfortunately, when I access my site via https:// it gives me the This web page has a redirect loop

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error in Chrome.